# Div with independent custom dropdown in bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have [this little profile dropdown](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMByEp), that I want to place in my bootstrap Navbar. As said, it's a dropdown, but there are two problems with that.
**1)** The dropdown expands to the side, weirdly like the following picture.
[image]
That leads to the second problem
**2)** It drags the entire navbar with it, expanding its height - this is where it would be nice to some how make it independent from the navbar...
And a possible **3)** Positioning - I am having a hard time to place this the right place - I just want it to have the same position as the normal navigation text, which I thought would be easier...

I made(/stole) my profile dropdown like this;

```
<div class="profile-wrapper">
    <div id="profile-button">
        <img style="width:35px;" src="http://planestorm.albert-website.design/img/avatars/profile_default.png">
        <p class="p-no-new-line">Username</p>
    </div>
    <div id="profile-dropdown">
        <ul id="profile-content">
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Avatar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Preferences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Signature</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

(without the PHP)

How would I do this?

Comment: Still unsolved. No progress.

Answer (score -1):

```
#profile-button, #profile-dropdown {display:block;width:100%;}
```

Comment: that didn't do anything really.